# como sumar las horas de datos tipo time?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de sumar únicamente las horas de un array que tiene datos tipo time, pero me arroja el siguiente error. **message: "Undefined offset: 2"**

```
$horas = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < $infoHorasCargadas; $i++) { 
        $horas = date('h', strtotime($infoHorasCargadas[$i]->horas_trabajadas)) + $horas;
      }
```

ejemplo de infoHorasCargadas:

```
infoHorasCargadas: [{id: 1214, fecha: "2020-10-01", descripcion: "SDFS", horas_trabajadas: "01:00"},…]

0: {id: 1214, fecha: "2020-10-01", descripcion: "SDFS", horas_trabajadas: "01:00"}
   descripcion: "SDFS"
   fecha: "2020-10-01"
   horas_trabajadas: "01:00"
   id: 1214
1: {id: 1215, fecha: "2020-10-01", descripcion: "DOS", horas_trabajadas: "02:30"}
   descripcion: "DOS"
   fecha: "2020-10-01"
   horas_trabajadas: "02:30"
   id: 1215
```

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de la data de `$infoHorasCargadas`

Comment: agregue el ejemplo de como se ve

Comment: el bucle es con `count`, no es menor a todo el array --> `for ($i=0; $i < count($infoHorasCargadas); $i++)` o podrías usar un `foreach`

Comment: si era eso me faltaba el count, gracias